# How to write numpy arrays to .txt file, starting at a certain line?

Tags: python, numpy, writetofile

I need to write 3 numpy arrays into a txt file. The head of the file looks like that:

```
#Filexy
#time  operation1 operation2
```

The numpy arrays look like the following:

```
time = np.array([0,60,120,180,...])
operation1 = np.array([12,23,68,26,...)]
operation2 = np.array([100,123,203,301,...)]
```

In the end, the .txt file should look like this (delimiter should be a tab):

```
#Filexy
#time  operation1 operation2
0   12   100
60  23    123
120  68   203
180  26   301
..  ...   ...
```

I tried it with "numpy.savetxt" - but I did not get the format that I want.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you tried, but you need to use the `header` parameter in `np.savetxt`. Also, you need to concatenate your arrays properly. The easiest way to do this is to use [`np.c_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html), which forces your 1D-arrays into 2D-arrays, and then concatenates them the way you expect.

```
>>> time = np.array([0,60,120,180])
>>> operation1 = np.array([12,23,68,26])
>>> operation2 = np.array([100,123,203,301])
>>> np.savetxt('example.txt', np.c_[time, operation1, operation2],
               header='Filexy\ntime  operation1 operation2', fmt='%d',
               delimiter='\t')
```

`example.txt` now contains:

```
# Filexy
# time  operation1 operation2
0   12  100
60  23  123
120 68  203
180 26  301
```

Also note the usage of `fmt='%d'` to get integer values in the output. `savetxt` will save as float by default, even for an integer array.

Regarding the delimiter, you just need to use the `delimiter` argument. It's not clear here, but there are, in fact, tabs between the columns. For instance, `vim` shows me tabs using dots:

```
# Filexy
# time  operation1 operation2
0·  12· 100
60· 23· 123
120·68· 203
180·26· 301
```

**Addendum:**

If you want to add headers *and* add an extra line before the arrays, you are better off creating a custom header, complete with your own comment characters. Use the `comment` argument to prevent `savetxt` from adding extra `#`'s.

```
>>> extra_text = 'Answer to life, the universe and everything = 42'
>>> header = '# Filexy\n# time operation1 operation2\n' + extra_text
>>> np.savetxt('example.txt', np.c_[time, operation1, operation2],     
               header=header, fmt='%d', delimiter='\t', comments='')
```

which produces

```
# Filexy
# time operation1 operation2
Answer to life, the universe and everything = 42
0   12  100
60  23  123
120 68  203
180 26  301
```

Comment: Don't forget `delimiter='\t'`

Comment: Great thank you! One additional thing --> how could i write in the third line (before the arrays start) a line that does not start with # ( in my case it would be just a number)

Comment: Thank you again - I tried your Addendum - but i missed the extra_num :). If possible the code should look like this: first line "#Filexy; second line "#time operation1 operation2; third line "42 (without a #); fourth --end..: the arrays. Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: Please also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487605/how-to-write-numpy-arrays-to-txt-file-starting-at-a-certain-line-numpy-versio :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f = open(name_of_the_file, "a")
np.savetxt(f, data, newline='\n')
f.close()
```