# How to write numpy arrays to .txt file, starting at a certain line? numpy version 1.6

Tags: python, numpy

At: [How to write numpy arrays to .txt file, starting at a certain line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39483774/how-to-write-numpy-arrays-to-txt-file-starting-at-a-certain-line)

People helped me to solve my problem - this works for numpy Version 1.7 or later. Unfortunatelly I have to use the version 1.6 - the follwoing code (thank you @Praveen)

```
extra_text = 'Answer to life, the universe and everything = 42'
header = '# Filexy\n# time operation1 operation2\n' + extra_text
np.savetxt('example.txt', np.c_[time, operation1, operation2],     
               header=header, fmt='%d', delimiter='\t', comments=''
```

give me an error with numpy 1.6

```
numpy.savetxt() got an unexpected keyword argument 'header' · Issue ...
```

Is there a work-around for Version 1.6 that produces the same result:

```
# Filexy
# time operation1 operation2
Answer to life, the universe and everything = 42
0   12  100
60  23  123
120 68  203
180 26  301
```

Comment: Why use a deprecated numpy at all? If it is about administrator privileges, look into pyenv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write your header first, then you dump the data.
Note that you'll need to add the `#` in each line of the header as `np.savetxt` won't do it.

```
time = np.array([0,60,120,180])
operation1 = np.array([12,23,68,26])
operation2 = np.array([100,123,203,301])
header='#Filexy\n#time  operation1 operation2'
with open('example.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(header)
    np.savetxt(f, np.c_[time, operation1, operation2],
                   fmt='%d',
                   delimiter='\t')
```